# how can test how many items had been deleted form the listbox using for in c#

Tags: c#

```
If ((textbox1.text - textbox2.text)==100 ||(textbox1.text - text2.text)==250)
{
   For (long i= textbox2.text;i < textbox1.text ;i++)
   {
           Listbox.remove (i)//listbox contain serials 
           // how can test how many items had been deleted form the listbox
   }
}
```

Comment: please copy code from VS IDE instead of hand writing.

Comment: Your code is completely non-functional.  Perhaps you could try writing some code and see how far you get.

Answer (score 0):

Before I start to answer, I'm assuming the code you included in your question is as follows:

```
If ((textbox1.text - textbox2.text)==100 ||(textbox1.text - text2.text)==250)
{
    For (Int i= textbox2.text;i < textbox1.text ;i++)
    {
        Listbox.remove (i)//listbox contain serials
        // how can test how many items had been deleted form the listbox
    }
}
```

If you're using the standard listbox, the correct syntax to remove items from it is this:`Listbox.Items.Remove(item)` [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items(v=vs.110).aspx)

In addition, you can't use `textbox.text` in arithmetic operations, you need to convert the strings to integers first using `Convert.Toint32`

To count the number of affected items, simply check if they exist before you remove them, and create a counter variable:

```
int tb1 = Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.text);
int tb2 = Convert.ToInt32(textbox2.text);
if ((tb1 - tb2)==100 ||(tb1 - tb2)==250)
{
    int counter=0;
    for (long i= tb2;i < tb1;i++)
    {
        if (Listbox.Items.Contains(i)) {
            counter++;
            Listbox.Items.Remove(i);
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(counter + " items were removed");
```

Comment: probably because you can't use strings in arithmetic operations, which is an issue on the first line, I wasn't looking for that as it wasn't part of the original question, it's edited now.

Comment: How are you declaring tb1 as a String and assigning it an int? Not to mention the capital `If` and `Int` and `For`... I can see that your code does not compile just by looking at it.

Comment: apologies, I don't actually have a compiler on me to verify syntax etc. problems you raised have been fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "counter" inside your loop where you are doing the delete.

Example:

```
      int counter = 0;

      //say, this is your loop for deletion of items on listbox
      for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
      {
          //if condition for deletion was met
          counter++;
      }

      //you can call counter after the loop, this will be the number of deleted items from your listbox
```